# Internal energy and bodies of different mass and temperature

Tags: energy

Is it true to say that a body of a higher mass has more internal energy than a body of lower mass or that a body of higher temperature has more internal energy than a body of lower temperature?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the two bodies are made of the same substance and all other applicable properties are identical, then **yes**, the total internal energy of a body is dependant on both its mass and its temperature -- *but mass only applies in this way for bodies*.

---

**Internal energy** can be defined as:

> the sum of various kinds of energy that the atoms or molecules of a substance posses

*(as defined by Cutnell and Johnson's Physics Fifth Edition)*

Generally, this is the sum of the molecular kinetic energy and the molecular potential energy (caused by interactions between particles).

---

Internal energy relies on **temperature** because the temperature is historically defined as a measurement of the average kinetic energy of a substance. Quantum physics changes how thermodynamics is expressed, but this definition works fine. As internal energy is directly dependant on kinetic energy, higher average molecular kinetic energy in a substance results in a higher internal energy in that substance.

---

The internal energy of a body relies on **mass** in a different manner. Mass is a count of all the particles in a body. Therefore, if *x* particles have a certain total internal energy, *2x* particles have a higher total energy, but not a higher internal energy per unit mass. The internal energy of the *2x* object may be higher, but if one touched both objects they would both feel the same; the areas (being identical per square unit of your skin) you are touching in both have identical internal energies. The *2x* object would simply take longer to reach equilibrium with your hand.

If that is confusing, just think of the total internal energy of a body depends on mass, but only because each unit mass has a certain additional internal energy.